# Borders in <div>

Tags: html, css

Problem image:

[image]

Well, how can you see, there's a border, that blue line below the black image, I need to remove it, but I can't, I don't know how to do it. I need some solutions.

```
<div align="center" style="background-color:#00F;">
  <img src="images/topimage.png">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="images/topimage bottomborder.png" style="width:100%;height:9px;">
</div>
```

Above's the code.

Comment: remove the image tag perhaps? this is a troll question probably, -1 and voted to close

Comment: It can be MANY things.image padding, margin, relative padding, margin, you should put your whole code and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are by default inline elements, so there, again by default, is space between the bottom edge of an image and the bottom edge of its container.

```
img {
    display: block
}
```

Alternatively, this should also work:

```
img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

Us an appropriate selector.